# Node and Express – Conditionally Displaying Pages

Tags: node.js, express, web3js

What I want to do seems elementary; but, I am running into some blocks.

All I want to do is display pages based on a condition.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/accessDenied.html');
  }
});
```

I am looking to grab information from the browser – I want to call a function from another browserify-ed file, and use the return value to determine which page is displayed to the user.

I can't run the server from app.js because it needs to be browserify-ed since it requires Web3.  And since the function relies on state, I am not sure how to access this state from the server file.

Comment: What do you mean *"grab information from the browser"*? Express is on the *server*, if it's coming from the browser it needs to be in the *request*.

Comment: well all I really need to do is grab data from the blockchain using web3

Answer (score 0):

You have to `post` data from the browser to the server either with a form or query parameter.

For example:

`web3.shh.post(object [, callback])`
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-shh.html#post

on the server site you need to extract those values and have to reply based on your posting.

[How to process POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js)

Unfortunately your use case is not clear ,but in general you might want to check out how to handle HTTP API communication.